# \renewcommand for \vec not working

Tags: math-mode, macros, vector

I don't like the look of the basic `\vec{v}` arrow, instead preferring the `\overrightarrow{}`.

I don't like typing all that though, so I added 
`\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\overrightarrow{#1}}` to my preamble, but this isn't working, I still get the normal `\vec` arrow.

My entire preamble is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in, bindingoffset=0in]{geometry}
\author{Brandon Myers}
\title{Homework \#7\\\Large Phys 4410}
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\overrightarrow{#1}}
\newcommand{\grad}{\overrightarrow{\nabla}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\Abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\end{document}
```

And I am compiling in XeLaTeX. What is going wrong with the redefinition?

Comment: Isn't there just a `}` missing? Just add a `}` : `\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\overrightarrow{#1}}`.

Comment: That is simply a typo here,  not when I actually run the code

Comment: When I insert `$\vec x$` in your example, it does use `\overrightarrow`.

Comment: I can reproduce your problem (but I can't solve it), it seems that the `\renewcommand` of `\vec` does nothing, if you create a new macro `\newcommand{\myvec}[1]{\overrightarrow{#1}}` it works.

Answer (score 3):

`unicode-math` does a large part of its job at begin document. In particular it redefines `\vec` at that point.

Just do

```
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\overrightarrow{#1}}}
```