# I want to automatically ... mathrm

Tags: symbols

I see the link [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/457656/renewcommand-for-vec-not-working)

I want the symbol i (italic) to automatically convert to "straight" by the code

```
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\hat}[1]{\hat{\mathrm{#1}}}}
```

but it's not working, please help me :(

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why you'd want that. Anyway, here's the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewCommandCopy{\latexhat}{\hat}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand{\hat}{m}
 {
  \latexhat
   {
    \str_case:nnF { #1 }
     {
      {i}{\mathchar16}
      {j}{\mathchar17}
     }
     {% other cases
      \mathrm{#1}
     }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\hat{a}+\hat{i}+\hat{j}+\hat{z}$

\end{document}
```

However, you should instead use a semantic command, say `\vrs` (for versor), without clobbering `\hat`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\vrs}{m}
 {
  \hat
   {
    \str_case:nnF { #1 }
     {
      {i}{\mathchar16}% dotless i
      {j}{\mathchar17}% dotless j
     }
     {% other cases
      \mathrm{#1}
     }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\vrs{a}+\vrs{i}+\vrs{j}+\vrs{z}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: the codes for dotless i and j work in standard `pdflatex` and may require adjustments for some math font packages; they're definitely wrong with `unicode-math`; in that case, use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\vrs}{m}
 {
  \hat
   {
    \str_case:nnF { #1 }
     {
      {i}{\symrm{^^^^0131}}% dotless i
      {j}{\symrm{^^^^0237}}% dotless j
     }
     {% other cases
      \symrm{#1}
     }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\vrs{a}+\vrs{i}+\vrs{j}+\vrs{z}$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you really, truly, want to redefine the `\hat` command so that all variables with a hat, and only those, are upright, you want to save the original `\hat` command before you redefine it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\oldhat\hat
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\hat}[1]{\oldhat{\mathrm{#1}}}}

\begin{document}
\[ \hat{i}
\]
\end{document}
```

If you wanted the hat to replace the dot on the i or j, it won’t, so you would want to define commands that place the accent on a dotless letter, such as (without `\hat` redefined)

```
\newcommand\ihat{\hat{\mathrm{\i}}}
\newcommand\jhat{\hat{\mathrm{\j}}}
```

You might also find it more practical to call the upright-with-hat command something different, such as `\uphat`.

If you want all variables to be upright, you are better off loading a package that does this, such as `\usepackage{eulervm}` or `\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}`.

Comment: I see :)
Thank you very much!